# Sending an Array from Android to Web Service

Tags: android, arrays, web-services

This is my code in Android

```
public String addRelation(ArrayList<Medida> pMedidas, Equipo pEquipo) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String eTagEquipo = Seguridad.encriptar(String.valueOf(pEquipo.getTag()));
    ArrayList<String> eMedidas = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = pMedidas.size(); //Obtenemos la cantidad de medidas relacionadas con el equipo

    for(int x=0;x<pMedidas.size();x++) {
        eMedidas.add(String.valueOf(pMedidas.get(x).getId()));
    }
    String urlParametros = "tagEquipo=" + eTagEquipo +
            "&idMedidas[]=" + eMedidas;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL ("http://www.myUrl.com/myFolder/WebService/myFolder/relEquipoMedidas.php");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); //Método POST

        //Longitud de datos que se envian

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ Integer.toString(urlParametros.getBytes().length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true); //Comando para la salida de datos

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParametros);
        wr.close();

        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line="";
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }
        else {
            return new String("False");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception");
    }

}
```

And this is my code in web service (PHP):

```
require_once '../../x/Conexion.php';

//----Recibimos los datos para realizar un alta-----  
$tagEquipo= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tagEquipo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //Seguridad de saneamiento
$idMedidas= (array)$_POST['idMedidas']; //Seguridad de saneamiento

//--------------------------------------------------  

$db = new Conexion();
$array = array();
//Primero se consulta que no exista actualmente
$cons = $db->query("SELECT _id FROM t__equipos WHERE _tag = '$tagEquipo';");
$idEquipo = $db->recorrer($cons)[0];
$cant = count($idMedidas);
$i = 0;
while($i < $cant)
{
    $ins = $db->query("INSERT INTO t__EquiMed(_idEquipo, _idMedida, _ordenMedida) VALUES ('$idEquipo', '$idMedidas[$i]', ($i+1))");

    $i++;
}
$array[0]['_resultado'] = 1;
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: have u solved your problem?

Comment: Yes my friend! I used "for"  and for each parameter I add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert your array list to Json Array String you can do this by many ways (You can look to [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/1.7.2) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson))
then u need to do this

```
        String data = jsonarray string;
        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(data);
        writer.close();
        outputStream.close();
```

Also it would be better if you use networking library rather using using default url connection like [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)